# Convert MySQL Query Into Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to convert the a MySQL query into a Laravel Eloquent query.

The following code will select a row of result where then it return the value of the weekNum column

```
function currentWeek() {

    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT weekNum FROM schedule WHERE DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -50 HOUR) < gameTimeEastern ORDER BY weekNum LIMIT 1 ";
    $query = $mysqli->query($sql);

    if ($query->num_rows > 0) {

        $row = $query->fetch_assoc();
        return $row['weekNum'];

    }
}
```

In Laravel in my SchedulesController this is what I am trying to achieve.

```
public function index()
{

    $schedules = Schedule::where('week', '=', 4)->get();

    return view('schedules.index', compact('schedules'));
}
```

Obviously I don't want to hard code the week in. This is my attempt.

```
public function index()
{
    $currentWeek = Schedule::distinct()
        ->where('gameTime', '<', Carbon::now()->addHours(100))
        ->orderBy('gameTime', 'desc')
        ->take(1)
        ->get();

    $schedules = Schedule::where('week', '=', $currentWeek->week)->get();

    return view('schedules.index', compact('schedules'));
}
```

But I get this error

```
ErrorException in SchedulesController.php line 25:
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$week
```

Comment: Can you do a die-dump of $currentWeek? There seems to be no week-property.

Comment: I get this

Collection {#157 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => Schedule {#158 ▼
      #fillable: array:15 [▶]
      #connection: null
      #table: null
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #perPage: 15
      +incrementing: true
      +timestamps: true
      #attributes: array:18 [▶]
      #original: array:18 [▶]
      #relations: []
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #appends: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #casts: []
      #touches: []
      #observables: []
      #with: []
      #morphClass: null
      +exists: true
    }
  ]
}

Comment: You can't access property's of a collection with magic methods. For this to work you need a Model. If you only ever need one result you can replace ->get() with ->first() to directly receive the model.

Comment: That work! Can you provide a solution so I can accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access the propertys because `->get()` returns  a collection of objects. For this to work you only need one object of your Eloquent Model.

If you only ever need one result you can replace `->get()` with `->first()` to directly receive the model object.